# How to make form code efficient and not redundant

Tags: jquery, html, forms, conditional-statements

I am making a custom questioner that will ask the user a set of yes and no questions. While the user is answering these questions, it will be sorting through the possibilities of what the final combination will be. I'm trying to find an easier way to accomplish this code wise.

Here is my jsfiddle to explain it a lot easier. Keep in mind, I know my method is redundant.
http://jsfiddle.net/tLaefycp/

```
<div id="Q1">
    <input type="radio">Yes
    <input type="radio">No
</div>

    <div id="Q2"> <!-- Yes to q1 -->
        <input type="radio">Yes
        <input type="radio">No
    </div>

    <div id="Q2"> <!-- No to Q1 -->
        <input type="radio">Yes
        <input type="radio">No
    </div>

        <div id="Q3"> <!-- Yes to q1 and q2 -->
            <input type="radio">Yes
            <input type="radio">No
        </div>

        <div id="Q3"> <!-- yes to q1 no to q2 -->
            <input type="radio">Yes
            <input type="radio">No
        </div>

        <div id="Q3"> <!-- no to q1 yes to q2 -->
            <input type="radio">Yes
            <input type="radio">No
        </div>

        <div id="Q3"> <!-- no to q1 no to q2 -->
            <input type="radio">Yes
            <input type="radio">No
        </div>
```

Comment: `id`s must be unique!!

Answer (score 2):

Create the questions and answers **programmatically**, directly with jquery with a defined array of the values instead of having it all in html from the get-go. I'm providing a simplified example structure for you, that you'll need to work out the logic. But it should give you a starting point.

If you iterate the generic questions and then once you get the answer, iterate the appropriate array from the `data` object, you can simplify your code. For instance, user chooses `trucks` then we know we have to iterate over `truckQuestions`.

```
var data = {genericQuestions : 
                [{question:"Do you like cars or trucks?",
                  answers: [["cars","carQuestions"],
                            ["trucks","truckQuestions"]]
                 }],
            truckQuestions :
                [{question:"Do you want a lift on your truck?",
                  answers: ["Yes","no"]
                  }
                 //More questions
                 ],
            carQuestions :
                [{question:"Do you want a lift on your truck?",
                  answers: ["Yes","no"]
                  }
                 //More questions
                 ]
           }
```

As for the html, have a template where you'd input the values (questions and answers) and reuse it each time. Remember that to access `truckQuestions` we can do `data.truckQuestions` but also  `data['truckQuestions']` which allows us to reuse the value of, in this case, `data.genericQuestions[0].answers[1][1]` (hopefully this doesn't confuse you)

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little confused. I know how arrays work and know some JS, but how you laid it out is a little weird. How does it show and hide questions, how does it keep track of which answer they chose...

Comment: The code i provided doesn't do any logic, it's a data structure for your questions that you could use. You wouldn't hide/show the questions, just update the data and answers. As far as tracking the answers it's also up to you, keep an array of answers, or whatever.  To clarify, you asked how to make the code less redundant, and I told you how, I'm not coding it for you though ;)

Comment: I realize you don't have to code it, I was just wondering the basics. Like do I need one array to hold all the questions for trucks, and one for cars? Then one for the answers?

Comment: I would do it the way I shown above, for every "branch" question, you'll need a new array. Since depending on the answer, the next question would be different. Another option is to have all answers on an array and instead of having the next branch alongside the answer, have the index of the next question.